# fetch array data from API in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

This is Model for My API and we will use this model in future. can Anyone tell me this is correct or Not. Im  a native user of SwiftUI.

```
public struct Temperatures {
        public let bookDetails: BookDetails

    public init(bookDetails: BookDetails) {
        self.bookDetails = bookDetails
    }
}


public struct BookDetails {
    public let data: [Datum]

    public init(data: [Datum]) {
        self.data = data
    }
}


public struct Datum : Hashable, Identifiable {
    public let id = UUID()
    public let title: String
    public let published: String
    public let url: String

    public init( title: String, published: String, url: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.published = published
        self.url = url
 

   }
}
```

And this is ViewModel
And i cant fetch the data of data[]

View Model For Prime Book And Showing Details

```
class PrimeBookVM: ObservableObject{
    @Published var datas = [Datum]()
    init(){
        let source = "https://********/api/book-search?is_prime"
        let url = URL(string: source)!
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
   
        session.dataTask(with: url){
            (data, _, err) in
            if err != nil{
                print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "Hello Error")
                return
            }
            
            let json = try!JSON(data: data!)
            for i in json["data"]{
                let published = i.1["published"].stringValue
                let title = i.1["title"].stringValue
                let url = i.1["url"].stringValue
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 
                    self.datas.append(Datum(title: title, published: published, url: url))
                 
                }
               
            }
               
        }
        .resume()
    }


}
```

> This is my View and try to fetch the detail of data array in api.

```
    struct PrimeBooksView: View{
    @StateObject var list = PrimeBookVM()
    var body: some View{
        ScrollView(.horizontal){
          HStack{
              ForEach(list.datas, id: \.self){ item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        WebImage(url: URL(string: item.url)!, options: .highPriority, context: nil)
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 180, height: 230)
                        Text(item.title)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .font(.system(size: 16))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("default"))
                        Text(item.published)
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                            .foregroundColor(Color("default"))
                    }
                    .padding(.all,4)
 
                        .background(Color.white).cornerRadius(8)
                        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 1)
                   
                }
                .padding(.all,1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Thank You So much in Advance for Help.

Comment: Please stop using `SwiftyJSON`. It's not topical anymore. Decode the JSON directly into the model with `JSONDecoder`. And please have a close look at the JSON. The key `data` is inside `BookDetails` which is **not** the root object. By the way `.padding(.all,4)` and `.padding(4)` does the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example code, with a working set of data model structs, and an updated `getData()` function
to fetch the data from the server. You still need to check the server documentation,
to determine which properties are optional.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        PrimeBooksView()
    }
}

class PrimeBookVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var datas = [Datum]()
    
    init() {
        getData()
    }
    
    func getData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://alibrary.in/api/book-search?is_prime") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiResponse.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.datas = results.bookDetails.data
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct PrimeBooksView: View{
    @StateObject var list = PrimeBookVM()
    
    var body: some View{
        ScrollView(.horizontal){
            HStack {
                ForEach(list.datas, id: \.self){ item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: item.url)) { image in
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 180, height: 230)
                        } placeholder: {
                            ProgressView()
                        }
                        Text(item.title)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .font(.system(size: 16))
                        Text(item.published)
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                    }
                    .padding(4)
                    .background(Color.white).cornerRadius(8)
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct ApiResponse: Codable {
    let bookDetails: BookDetails
    let bookSearch: String?
    let uploadTypeID: Int
    let stackID: String
    let data: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bookDetails, bookSearch
        case uploadTypeID = "upload_type_id"
        case stackID = "stack_id"
        case data
    }
}

public struct BookDetails: Codable {
    let currentPage: Int
    let data: [Datum]
    let firstPageURL: String
    let from, lastPage: Int
    let lastPageURL, nextPageURL, path: String
    let perPage: Int
    let prevPageURL: String?
    let to, total: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data, from, path, to, total
        case currentPage = "current_page"
        case firstPageURL = "first_page_url"
        case lastPage = "last_page"
        case lastPageURL = "last_page_url"
        case nextPageURL = "next_page_url"
        case perPage = "per_page"
        case prevPageURL = "prev_page_url"
    }
}

public struct Datum : Hashable, Identifiable, Codable {
    public let id = UUID() // <-- could be Int
    public let title: String
    public let published: String
    public let url: String

    public init( title: String, published: String, url: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.published = published
        self.url = url
   }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title, published, url
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. and please give me proper guidance of using API in Swiftui